# Specifying A DateTime, Double PointPairList?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I want to graph some data with Date vs Value.
The problem is that I don't know how to make a PointPairList accept DateTime values and Double values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the framework are you using. If it's .NET 4 you can use a Tuple:

```
var dataPoints = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>();
```

If you are using an earlier framework version, you can instead create a simple class to hold the data points:

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

...and use that instead:

```
var dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();
```

Comment: Or use the `KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>` in `System.Collections`

Answer (score 2):

ZedGraph has its own Date format: [XDate](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_XDate.htm)
You can easily convert DateTime to XDate.

More info:
http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=What_is_an_XDate_struct%3F
Example:
http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Tutorial:Date_Axis_Chart_Demo

Comment: The last two links are (unfortunately) broken now.

Comment: @Peter, yes, the zedgraph.org is no longer availble